# Moving subview in a super view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a view1, view2, and view3․ view2 is a subview for view1, and view3 is a subview for view2. I want to move view3 inside view1 and view2, but when I release it inside view1 I can't pick it again.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.thriedView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

- (void) handlePan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture {
    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:panGesture.view];
        panGesture.view.center = CGPointMake(panGesture.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                             panGesture.view.center.y + translation.y);

        [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:panGesture.view];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you release the third view outside the second view, it is outside its superview. A view outside its superview cannot, by default, be touched (i.e. it cannot receive touch events). That is why you "can't pick it again".

Comment: And how can I move view3 inside view2 and view1?

Comment: Don't make view3 a subview of view2. Make them both subviews of view 1 only.

Comment: isn't there any way to solve this problem, without changing the hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, you could change the rules of _hit-testing_. I call that _hit-test munging_. See this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing